# radio button check selection change event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html

```
 <div id="options_div">
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_1" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label id="VoteAns_269_1_lbl" contenteditable="true">6 : 00 PM</label>       
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_1"></label><br>            
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_2" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label contenteditable="true">7 : 00 PM</label>
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_2"></label><br>
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_3" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label contenteditable="true">8 : 00 PM</label>
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_3"></label><br>            
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_4" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label contenteditable="true">9 : 00 PM</label>
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_4"></label><br>            
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_5" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label contenteditable="true">10 : 00 PM</label>
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_5"></label><br>
     <input name="Names" type="radio" class="VoteAns" id="VoteAns_269_6" value="Values" contenteditable="false"/>
     <label contenteditable="true">11 : 00 PM</label>
     <label id="VoteAnsOP_269_6"></label><br>            
</div>
```

this is js

```
 /*
    $jq("input[name=Names]:radio").on('change', function(){
        console.log("dfdfd");
    });
    $jq("input[name=Names]:radio").click(function(){
        console.log("dfdfd");
    });
    console.log($jq("#VoteAns_268_1").val());
    $jq('.VoteAns').change(function (){
    console.log("vote Answers");
    });
    */
  /*  $jq("input[name=Names]:radio").change(function () {
        conosle.log("radiobutton changes");
    })*/

 /*   $jq(".VoteAns").change(function(){
        conosle.log("VoteAns");
    });*/
    /*$jq(".VoteAns").on('change',function(){
        conosle.log("VoteAns");
    });
    $jq("#VoteAns_269_1_lbl").on('change',function(){
        conosle.log("VoteAns123");
    });*/
    /*$jq(".VoteAns").click(function(){
        alert("kk");
    })*/
     $jq("input:radio[name='Names']").change(function(){
        alert("input11!!");
    });
```

As u can see in ***comments*** I have **tried all these code but none of this working form me**. tired of searching and trying different codes whats the problem please help.

I want to display  specific html on different radio option click

Comment: did you check my fiddle?

Comment: @Pekka yes you have syntax error but fiddly working amzaing. but code didnt work in my project

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan missing `]` i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax. you have not closes the square bracket while using attribute equals selector:

```
$("input:radio[name='Names']").change(function(){
   alert("input11!!");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7x0d5yr/)**

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: closing square braces. here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/q7x0d5yr/

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gZAT/489/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="greeting" id="hi" checked="checked" value="hi">hi
<input type="radio" name="greeting" id="hello" value="hello">hello
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name=greeting]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'hi') {
            alert("hi");
        } else if (this.value == 'hello') {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
});
```

in your code, you are missing a `]`.That is, your new code would be like

```
$("input:radio[name='Names']").click(function(){
    alert("input!!");
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gZAT/490/)

Comment: $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: in what? fiddle or your local website? any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyuxferf/2/)

```
$("input[name='Names']").change(function () {
    alert($(this).next().text());
});
```

change your `jq` to `$` and a bit cleaner selector from `"input:radio[name='Names']"` to `"input[name='Names']"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
         $("input[name='Names']:radio").change(function () {
              alert('input!!');
          });
```

if you are using $jq then make sure that u have that line on top.

```
           $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

           $jq("input[name='Names']:radio").change(function () {
              alert('input!!');
           });
```